# Filter one or more matched strings to reduce data set

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filter

I am trying to filter a set of data based on strings that are stored in localStorage. The number of strings could be 0 - 4. (If the string exists then I split it at the comma).

Currently my function loops through the data, and reduces the set but only according to the first string.

I need some way to loop over the data x times and store the filtered data into a new array using push (I presume). I guess it's passing the first string selector and reducing the set.

I have a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/fxv94185/[1](https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/fxv94185/)

For simplicity I am simply storing the strings into a variable (rather than using jsfiddle local storage). `var chQualityFilters = "ok,ko"` this can be changed in the fiddle to an empty string, or one or more of the four selectors 'ok', 'ko', 'spark', 'oos'.

Full code is here:

```
var url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/14xw8x';
var dataWrapper = $('.data-wrapper');
var endSpan = '</span><span>';
var spanWide = '</span><span class="wide">';
var chQualityFilters = "ok,ko"; // this can be 1 or more of 'ok', 'ko', 'spark', 'oos'

returnQualityData = function(){
  $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:url,
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data){
      if (chQualityFilters !== null && chQualityFilters !== 'none') {
        getSetFilters();
      }
      var filteredData = data.filter(function(d){
        for(var i=0; i<chQualityFilters.length; i++){ // how to loop over the chQualityFilters array a second time. 
          return (d.Status.toLowerCase() == chQualityFilters[i]);
        }
      });
      console.log(filteredData);
      dataWrapper.empty();
      dataWrapper.prepend('<li class="title"><span>'
                          +'Date' + spanWide
                          +'Database name' + spanWide
                          +'Table name'+ endSpan
                          +'Lake <br />volume'+ endSpan
                          +'Source <br />volume'+ endSpan
                          +'Difference'+ endSpan
                          +'Null %'+ endSpan
                          +'Std. index'+ endSpan
                          +'Hazard <br />index'+ endSpan
                          +'Source data available'+ endSpan
                          +'Status'
                          +'</span></li>');
      for(var i in filteredData){
        var statusLowerCase = filteredData[i]["Status"].toLowerCase();
        var year = filteredData[i]["Data Date"].slice(0,4);
        var month = filteredData[i]["Data Date"].slice(4,6);
        var day = filteredData[i]["Data Date"].slice(6,8);
        var date = day+ "/" +month+ "/" +year;
        dataWrapper.append('<li class="' +statusLowerCase+ '"><a href="#"><span>'
                           +date+ spanWide
                           +filteredData[i]["Database Name"]+ spanWide
                           +filteredData[i]["Table Name"]+ endSpan 
                           +filteredData[i]["Lake Volume"]+ endSpan 
                           +filteredData[i]["Source Volume"]+ endSpan 
                           +filteredData[i].Difference+ endSpan 
                           +filteredData[i]["Null Percent"]+ endSpan 
                           +filteredData[i]["Standardisation Index"]+ endSpan 
                           +filteredData[i]["Hazard Index"]+ endSpan 
                           +filteredData[i]["Source Data Available"]+ '</span><span class="status hideFont ' +statusLowerCase+ '">' +statusLowerCase
                           + '</span></a>'
                           + '<ul class="sub-data">' 
                           + '<li><span>Source database name</span> ' +filteredData[i]["Source Database Name"] + '</li>'
                           + '<li><span>Ingestion frequency</span> ' +filteredData[i]["Ingestion Frequency"]+ '</li>'
                           + '<li><span>Unload type</span> ' +filteredData[i]["Unload Type"]+ '</li>'
                           + '<li><span>Number of columns</span> ' +filteredData[i]["Number Of Columns"]+ '</li>'
                           + '</ul>'
                           + '</li>');
      }
    },
    error:function(status){
    },
    complete:function(){
    }
  });
  return false;
}();

getSetFilters = function() {
  var qualityFilterInput = $('[name="filterStatus"]');
  if (chQualityFilters !== null && chQualityFilters !== 'none') {
    chQualityFilters = chQualityFilters.split(',');
  }

  if(chQualityFilters){
    for(var i=0; i<chQualityFilters.length; i++){
      $('[data-filter="status"] [value=' +chQualityFilters[i]+ ']').prop('checked',true);
    }
  }
}
```

Sample of data:

```
[  
   {  
      "Database Name":"bu",
      "Table Name":"pro_fis",
      "Status":"OOS",
      "Ingestion Frequency":"Daily - Mon-Sun",
      "Unload Type":"Full",
      "Source Database Name":"n/a",
      "Data Date":"20170426",
      "Number Of Columns":"31",
      "Lake Volume":"384931",
      "Source Volume":"0",
      "Difference":"384931",
      "Difference Percent":"100",
      "Null Percent":"0",
      "Standardisation Index":"79.7425",
      "Hazard Index":"0.000002",
      "Source Data Available":"No"
   },
   {  
      "Database Name":"ca",
      "Table Name":"prepart_",
      "Status":"Spark",
      "Ingestion Frequency":"Daily - Mon-Sun",
      "Unload Type":"Full",
      "Source Database Name":"bp1",
      "Data Date":"20171021",
      "Number Of Columns":"43",
      "Lake Volume":"0",
      "Source Volume":"1699573",
      "Difference":"1699573",
      "Difference Percent":"0",
      "Null Percent":"0",
      "Standardisation Index":"0",
      "Hazard Index":"0",
      "Source Data Available":"Yes"
   },
   {  
      "Database Name":"ca",
      "Table Name":"pte_co",
      "Status":"Spark",
      "Ingestion Frequency":"Daily - Mon-Sun",
      "Unload Type":"Full",
      "Source Database Name":"sv09",
      "Data Date":"20171021",
      "Number Of Columns":"13",
      "Lake Volume":"0",
      "Source Volume":"2848018",
      "Difference":"2848018",
      "Difference Percent":"0",
      "Null Percent":"0",
      "Standardisation Index":"0",
      "Hazard Index":"0",
      "Source Data Available":"Yes"
   }
]
```

Full dataset is here (as used in the fiddle): https://api.myjson.com/bins/14xw8x

Comment: Not getting what the question is.

Comment: If the variable `chQualityFilters == 'ok'`, loop through the data and remove any records that do not match `status = ok`. If `chQualityFilters = 'ok,oos'`, split the string at the comma, we now need to loop through the data twice. First filter by `Status == ok`, then loop again and add `Status == 'oos'` to the filtered data. Does that make sense? return Status == 'ok' && Status == 'oos'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change:

```
for(var i=0; i<chQualityFilters.length; i++){ 
   return (d.Status.toLowerCase() == chQualityFilters[i]);
}
```

to something like:

```
return chQualityFilters.includes(d.Status.toLowerCase())
```

Comment: Yes, I had just implemented your code in the fiddle @charlietfl and it worked, so I was going to award you the points. But this solution seems very similar.

Comment: @lharby your code would have worked if you had simply converted string to array